# Loading component by string name (lazy)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an application with approximately 1600 different screens/components. I need to know how to use ReactJS, JSX, TypeScript and Redux to open these programs on demand (lazy loading).

These programs do not use Routes and are loaded through a menu that is generated dynamically through data that comes from the database. In the database I keep the name of the React components, but I can not load these screens/components through the React menu.

Comment: Type this: https://codesandbox.io/s/oj821z93qz

I tried to use this example, but it is not using TypeScript

Comment: When I try to run the CodeSandbox code, I get this code: https://prnt.sc/m17by9

Comment: What version of React are you using? Also, what are your build tools?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst The latest versions of React, Redux, Webpack and TypeScript

Comment: Have you looked into React Suspense and/or Webpack lazy loading of modules? It sounds like you essentially want each page to be its own bundle

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use it? I've tried several ways, but none worked when using Redux, Webpack and Typescript

Comment: I don't use TS or lazy loading myself right now, sorry